# Do we want hats?

Tags: discussion, hats

A year ago Stack Exchange ran a [Hat promotional event](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/) where you could earn "hats" for your gravatar (profile icon) to wear. Stack Exchange is going to do a second run of this promo, but they're going to run it on all sites, *provided the site wants it*. The hats will be more generic and not as ridiculous (no decapitated Wampa hats). Mods give the final go-ahead here, but I figured I'd ask and see; once there's a clear consensus one way or another we'll handle the rest.

Hats would be earned by completing tasks like editing a question, getting upvotes, stuff you do to get badges, but you can show them off while the event is active. These would show up only on the /User page and on question pages, and it sounds like there would be an option to turn them off.

So, as a community, do we want the hats promo? Y/N?

Comment: [Obligatory Monty Python Reference](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2QJvc_SxFQ)

Comment: @Erics I see your Monthy Python and raise you [Don Hertzfeldt](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEiyBbP28g8)

Comment: Just to double-check - the hat-winning criteria are set by Stack Exchange centrally, correct? I was wondering if there was a way we could tie this into the Improvement Drive in some way. (http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1151/stack-improvement-drive-ux)

Comment: @dhmholley according to SE hats are 100% the same on all sites (unless they opt out) so there's no tie-in. But I imagine there'll be some for asking questions/etc which will organically be similar to the improvement drive's focus

Comment: I can essentially confirm what @BenBrocka said. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. Yes indeed we do want hats.

Answer (score 4):

It's geeky enough, so of course **yes**!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, who doesn't like hats?

Seriously though, what exactly would would have to happen for us *not* to take hats?  I suggest:

- If the total votes for this meta post are **negative** by 27th November then we say no to having them on the site (and just give our avatars their own hats through gravatar anyway)
- If this question is in **positive** votes by 27th November then we go ahead.

Comment: I was thinking more like a couple days, not until the deadline. If someone's crazy against the idea that should be enough time, otherwise I doubt there will be an issue.

Comment: @BenBrocka Also note that if the site opts in, any ***individual*** user can opt out by clicking a button. That will turn off all hats for that user AND that user won't be seen sporting any hats whatsoever. :)

Comment: @Aarthi so to be clear - an individual who opts out via the button will not see *anyone* wearing hats at all, and won't be awarded hats themselves? Sort of like a toggle on/off for the site just for them so the site appears as it is now?

Comment: @JonW I believe they'll "earn" hats, but they won't be seen as wearing any, and they won't receive notifications about new hats. Basically, their hats go into the ether.